# Java Round up Any Number

Tags: java, math, int, rounding

I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for regarding a simple question: how do I round up any number to the nearest `int`?

For example, whenever the number is 0.2, 0.7, 0.2222, 0.4324, 0.99999 I would want the outcome to be 1.

So far I have

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil(a / 100);
```

It doesn't seem to be doing the job, though.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 100 in your sample code?

Comment: I bet your `a` has integer type.

Comment: Tell us what your inputs are, and your expected outputs.

Comment: yea ur right a is an int... thanks for pointing that out. 100.0 sorted it for me.

Comment: I'm guessing what he wants is a/100 rounded up, but yeah, the question could use some clarification.

Comment: **NOTE: At [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139382/java-rounding-up-to-an-int-using-math-ceil/21830188#21830188) question better answers are provided.**

Answer (score 344, accepted):

[`Math.ceil()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) is the correct function to call. I'm guessing `a` is an `int`, which would make `a / 100` perform integer arithmetic. Try `Math.ceil(a / 100.0)` instead.

```
int a = 142;
System.out.println(a / 100);
System.out.println(Math.ceil(a / 100));
System.out.println(a / 100.0);
System.out.println(Math.ceil(a / 100.0));
System.out.println((int) Math.ceil(a / 100.0));
```

Outputs:

```
1
1.0
1.42
2.0
2
```

See http://ideone.com/yhT0l

Comment: this only if "a" is double

Comment: ^^ "a" needs to be a double or cast a double.

Comment: `a` is an `int` in this example, and it works as suggested. When doing `int / float` the result is a `float`, as demonstrated in the output. Try out the link.

Answer (score 22):

I don't know why you are dividing by 100 but here my assumption `int a;`

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil( ((double)a) / 100);
```

or

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil( a / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
int RoundedUp = (int) Math.ceil(RandomReal);
```

This seemed to do the perfect job. Worked everytime.

Answer (score 12):

10 years later but that problem still caught me.

So this is the answer to those that are too late as me.

This does not work

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil(a / 100);
```

Cause the result `a / 100` turns out to be an integer and it's rounded so Math.ceil 
can't do anything about it.

You have to avoid the rounded operation with this

```
int b = (int) Math.ceil((float) a / 100);
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option. Use basics of math:

`Math.ceil(p / K)` is same as `((p-1) // K) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just: 
You will receive a float or double and want it to convert it to the closest round up then just do   `System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(yourfloat));` 
it'll work perfectly

Answer (score -2):

Assuming a as double and we need a rounded number with no decimal place . Use Math.round() function.
This goes as my solution .

```
double a = 0.99999;
int rounded_a = (int)Math.round(a);
System.out.println("a:"+rounded_a );

Output : 
a:1
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer, as it is asked here to round UP
if a=0.2 the result will be 0