# Java: printing the numbers above the index of the median error

Tags: java

I am trying to print every number that has an index above the median. However, i keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int list[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int list1[] = new int[2];
int start = (int)(Math.ceil(list.length/2));
String output = "";

 for(int i = start; i < list.length; i++) {
    int indexB = (i - 3);
    list1[indexB] = list[i]; //The error is concerned about this line of code        
 }
    for(int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++) {
       output += list1[j] + " ";
    }
       System.out.print(output); 


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here,

> `int start = (int)(Math.ceil(list.length/2));` return 2 whereas
>
> ```
> `int start = (int) (Math.ceil((double) 5 / (double) 2));` returns 3
> ```

```
int indexB = (i - 3);
```

Here `i = start = 2`, so indexB becomes -1, which is not an index

so it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Also loop starts from `i=2 -> i<5, so for values of i=2,3,4`

Some code changes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int start = (int) (Math.ceil(list.length / 2));

        int list1[] = new int[list.length  - start];
        String output = "";

        for (int i = start; i < list.length; i++) {
            int indexB = (i - start);
            list1[indexB] = list[i]; // The error is concerned about this line
                                        // of code
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++) {
            output += list1[j] + " ";
        }
        System.out.print(output);

    }
```

**output**

```
3 4 5
```

Comment: @SamuelTober `(int)(Math.ceil(list.length/2));` return 2, pls check

Comment: If i put in 2.5 into the Math.ceil() function it return 3 however if i put in (5/2) it returns 2... Why is this?

Comment: @SamuelTober refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139382/java-rounding-up-to-an-int-using-math-ceil)