# Java rounding using double (monetary calculation)

Tags: java, decimal, rounding, currency

For my project I have decided to store money as an Integer (pence) instead of using BigDecimal and Co.

But I'm having some trouble with percentage calculation and two decimal rounding.

for example I wish to calculate the 2.9% of 11.88$ which would be:

```
1188 * 0.029 = 34.452 = 35 (so 0.35$)
(the .4 round to .5 so the 34 round 35)
```

But cannot manage to arrive to this result using Math.round or Math.ceil.

```
double r = Math.round(34.452)  
r = 34
```

is there a way in Java using double/long to round as in my example ?

(Note: using BigDecimal and setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING) is works perfectly)

1.03356
1.03356

Comment: Why do you want .34452 to "round" to .35? That's not how standard mathematical rounding works; it's _only_ the leftmost truncated digit that matters: .34500 and above rounds to .35, and .34499 and below rounds to .34. Alternatively, _banker's rounding_ is almost identical, except that if the truncated part is 500, you round towards even numbers.

Comment: *"(the .4 round to .5 so the 34 round 35),"* That is not how rounding works.

Comment: There is a similar question and a complete answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139382/java-rounding-up-to-an-int-using-math-ceil

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset and clcto, thanks. I should have paid more attention in class

Comment: If it's a comfort, I also initially misunderstood rounding when I learned about it and thought that you were supposed to cascade all of the digits :)