# Jqgrid - Calculation of noOfPages value

Tags: jqgrid

I was referring to the Instant jqGrid book to set up the grid. The noOfPages attribute is calculated as follows.

```
//Prepare the response
$numberOfPages = ceil( $numberOfRows / $rowsPerPage );
```

I could see that for 581 records with rowPerPage=25, the noOfPages were appearing as 23.

```
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(581/25));//23
```

I was expecting a value as 24 with the last page containing the records [576-581]. So here, we are missing these 6 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use Java, where ceil of two integer gives integer. I suggest you to look at [this theard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139382/java-rounding-up-to-an-int-using-math-ceil)

To resume the possible solutions are:

1. int n = (int) Math.ceil((double) a / b));
2. int n = a / b + (a % b == 0) ? 0 : 1;
3. int n = (a + b - 1) / b;

Select one which will meet best your requierments