# Why isn't math.ceiling rounding up my number? java

Tags: java, ceil

Trying to write this script that works with inputs that often go up into hundreds of billions. However, Math.ceil won't round upwards?

```
int clayturns  = (int)Math.ceil(clayneeded / 7500000000L);
System.out.println((int) Math.ceil(clayneeded / 7500000000L));
System.out.println("we need " + clayturns + "turns");
System.out.println("we need " + clayneeded + " clay added to our specific village.");
```

under here I have the eclipse console output. As you can see clayneeded isn't blank. As if that's the case then clayturns should always be something, it can't be zero, but it is.

```
we need 0turns
we need 3021588634 clay needed to our specific village.
```

Please let me know what you think. Does math ceil not work with Longs?

Comment: What type of is `clayneeded`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java rounding up to an int using Math.ceil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139382/java-rounding-up-to-an-int-using-math-ceil)

Answer (score 3):

is `clayneeded` an `int`/`long`?  if you're doing `int`/`long` division, it'll truncate any fractional component before it gets to the `Math.ceil`.  Given the size of your inputs, I'd stay away from `float`s/`double`s, and use `BigDecimal`s to do the math accurately here.

Comment: its a long. What's bigdecimal s

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html -- but also see the answers to the possible duplicate question that @BreakBB pointed out for alternative options not using `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `clayneeded` has integer type (probably `long`). So `clayneeded/7500000000L` is **integer division** (quotient), thus `ceil` computes the ceiling of an integer, so itself.

So you can compute it like this (if the remainder of the integer division is not nul then the ceiling must produce the next integer) :

```
long remainder = clayneeded % 7500000000L;
long result = (clayneeded/7500000000L)+(remainder!=0?1:0);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you store your clayturns variable inside an integer. There is an Integer overflow happening, which returns 0.

The maximum value for an integer is +2,147,483,647.

Comment: No, constant used is `long` so every other integer would have been converted to `long`.