# write a java function for rounding the whole integer number into its nearest round number for example: 53 to 60

Tags: java, rounding

I want to write a java function for rounding the whole integer number into its nearest round number for example:

> 53 to 60
>   68 to 70
>   35 to 40
>   50 to 50
>   etc

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself and describe the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Would 53 round to 60? Surely It would round to 50.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Round up Any Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540684/java-round-up-any-number)

Comment: Ignore me I answered in javascript not java.

Comment: What would 50 become? Would it stay as 50?

Comment: I know @Vistari but the functionality I a working on needs the next round figure.

Comment: @ZacBraddy its ok javascript will also work for me

Comment: yes @AndyTurner 50 will remain 50

Comment: @Snehal please add that to your examples.

Comment: thank you guys..got it working :-)

Answer (score 3):

For your question nearest whole number would be for 53 -> 50 not 60

Any way for your question, it seems you need next multiple of 10. 
Very simple answer can be:

```
 ans = (input%10) ? ((input/10)+1)*10 : input
```

Which simplifies like to,

1. input = 52
2. (input/10)+1 = 6
3. 6*10 = 60

Comment: This doesn't work for the 50->50 case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out error, i have corrected it now.

Comment: `(52 % 10) + 1 = 3`?

Comment: Sorry mistakenly written wrong code in the comment, corrected it now.

Comment: This isn't actually valid Java.

Comment: just have to define variables as integers otherwise it will work in java.

Answer (score 0):

To round a positive integer `n` up to the nearest (positive) multiple `m`:

```
(n + m - 1) / m
```

This avoids the unnecessary widening to `double` that you'd get by using `Math.ceil`.

e.g.

```
(n + 9) / 10
```

rounds up to the nearest 10.