# Java- Rounding up anything after 2 decimal points *Not just %.2f*

Tags: java, printf, decimal

So as the top says. I am stuck on a rather simple problem but its seems I am stuck.

Example: 
x = 3.141

When I use `printf("x is: %.2f", x);`
it spits out:  `X is 3.14`

Well to calculate state tax anything above a cent needs to be rounded up so 3.141 should be 3.15. Is there a simple printf I can modify or an additional tag I can add? Or will I need to go a round about way to calculate the additional bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Round up Any Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540684/java-round-up-any-number)

Comment: i guess it would be a duplicate if you could math.ceil a specific decimal limit. but not exactly the same different need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to add 0.005 to the number.

PS: Make sure you calculate everything strictly in BigDecimal. Using double for money is not recommended.

Comment: Simple solution to a simple problem. Thankyou!!

Comment: If the tax was exactly 3.00, won’t this cause the tax to be displayed as 3.01?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `printf`, use a `DecimalFormat` with `RoundingMode.CEILING`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
String rounded = df.format(x)
System.out.printf("x is: %s", rounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
public static float roundUp(float num, int positions) {
    int tmp = ((int)(num*Math.pow(10, positions)));
    tmp = tmp + 10 - tmp%10;
    return ((float)(tmp/Math.pow(10, positions)));
}
```

You can obtain what you want by calling

```
roundUp(num, 3);
```

Or if you want a less-generic method, you can as well use:

```
public static float roundUp(float num) {
    int tmp = ((int)(num*1000.0f));
    tmp = tmp + 10 - tmp%10;
    return ((float)(tmp/1000.0f));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.ceil(x * 100) * 0.01
```

Avoids magic rounding numbers (do you need to add 0.9, or 0.99, or 0.999, etc)