# Divide integers in sections [Java]

Tags: java, arraylist, sections

I want to divide the input I get from the user in different num sections in java. And then as output there have to come how many numbers are in each section.
E.g.
1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

- in section (0 - 3) there are 4 numbers
- in section (4 - 6) there are 4 numbers
- in section (7 - 9) there are 3 numbers
- and in section (10 - 12) there are 3 numbers

I have no idea how to manage this.

Comment: You could set a limit that you increase by 3 every step and then iterate over your input list while the values are <= your limit

Comment: It's a difference in logic if you want to divide only this specific array or any array of any size containing arbitrary `int`s (or `long`s`?)... Please explain in detail how the grouping should be done for an array of size `n`.

Comment: "in section (4 - 6) there are 4 numbers " why?

Comment: @tannerli Thanks for the advice and the first thoughts

Comment: @deHaar it is not for a specific array. I already implemented all and just stuck at this step. For easy understanding here I asked with this example

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca 4, 4, 5, 6 like in example above

Comment: Oh, so you mean you have an array and you want to count how many numbers in a specific range the array contains?

Comment: There are a number of different approaches that would work. A simple approach would be to loop through the numbers, and for each one, work out what group it's in. When you know the group, you can increment a group counter.
But you'd get a better response to your question If you attempted to write some code yourself, and ask people how it could be improved.

Comment: @Federico Exactly

Comment: @Nick Ok I‘ll do it thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to put every list `element` into the corresponding bucket

The `ID` of a bucket is computed by `element-1/3` where `/` is a `division` with the `remainder`

Such division produces a `quotient` and a `remainder`, and the `ID` of bucket is equal `quotient`

It works except for 0 so it can be put by if condition to the first bucket

Answer (score 0):

So.. I have one idea. In this particular example you have step 3 for groups. Maybe let's divide numbers on 3 with round up and use result as an group number. For example: `Math.ceil(1/3.0) == 1`, so this is 1st group (0-3), for `Math.ceil(5/3.0) == 2`, so this is 2nd group, and etc. But notice that `Math.ceil(0/3.0) == 0`.

Ref about rounding up: [Java Round up Any Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540684/java-round-up-any-number)

P.S.: Please, don't blame me, my first answer on stackoverflow.