# How to round up a floating-point number in Java

Tags: java, android, math

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double x=120.38;
      System.out.println(Math.round(x‬));
    }
}
```

*Output: `120`*

**But I want an output of `121`**
**Rounding off any decimal values to 1 whole number**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Round up Any Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540684/java-round-up-any-number)

Comment: Using Math.ceil() solves it

Comment: *"[Rounding off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_off)"* To almost everybody, that means rounding to **nearest** number, and `120` is the nearest whole number to `120.38`. Did you perhaps mean you want rounding **up**? Perhaps it would be a good idea to check the javadoc of [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) to learn the Java terminology used for naming the various rounding modes: Up, Down, Ceiling, Floor, Half-Up (aka "round off"), Half-Down, and Half-Even (aka "Banker's rounding").

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Math.round` with `Math.ceil`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use : Math.ceil(x)
It will works for you